# "Marginal" distributions of probability measure on separable Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, banach-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space, and consider a random variable $X: (\Omega, \mathcal F)\longrightarrow (S,\mathcal S)$, where $S$ is a separable real Banach space. It is well-known that $X$ induces a probability measure $\mu$ on $(S,\mathcal S)$.

In the case $S = C(T)$ or $S = L^p(T)$, with $T\subset\mathbb R$, the probability measure $\mu$ is uniquely characterized by its finite dimensional marginal distributions $(\pi_J)_*\mu$ with $J\subseteq T$ finite. Here $(\pi_J)_*\mu := \mu\circ\pi^{-1}_J$, and $\pi_J^{-1}$ denotes the preimage of the coordinate projection $\pi_J:S\longrightarrow\{\text{all functions $J\longrightarrow\mathbb R$}\}$ with $\pi_J(f) = (f(j))_{j\in J}$.

In a general separable Banach space, we don't have coordinate projections. Does the concept of marginal distribution exist nevertheless? If yes, how is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a very good concept of finite dimensional marginal distributions of $\mu$ when $S$ is a general separable Banach space, or more generally when $\mu$ is a Radon probability and $S$ is a real topological vector space that is separated by its dual. This is tied to the notion of "cylindrical probability" on $S$.

---

**Cylindrical probabilities**

Denote by $\mathscr F$ the set of all closed linear subspaces of $S$ with finite codimension in $S$ and for every $E\in\mathscr F$, denote by $\pi_E$ the quotient map from $S$ to $S/E$. The set $\mathscr F$ is upward directed for the order given by $\supseteq$. So for every $E,F\in\mathscr F$ such that $E\supseteq F$, if you denote by $\pi_{FE}$ the unique linear map from $S/E$ to $S/F$ satisfying $\pi_F=\pi_{FE}\circ\pi_E$, the finite dimensional quotients $S/E$ together with the maps $\pi_{FE}$ form a [projective system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) of vector spaces.

A *cylindrical probability* on $S$ is a projective system of probabilities on the projective system of vector spaces given by the quotients $S/E$ and the maps $\pi_{FE}$, i.e. a family $(\lambda_E)_{E\in\mathscr F}$ where each $\lambda_E$ is a Radon probability on $S/E$ satisfying $\lambda_F=(\pi_{FE})_\ast(\lambda_E)$ for every $E,F\in\mathscr F$ such that $E\supseteq F$.

---

**Link with Radon probabilities**

Now, when $\mu$ is a Radon probability on $S$, you can consider the family $((\pi_E)_\ast\mu)_{E\in\mathscr F}$ of the "finite dimensional marginal distributions" of $\mu$. This family is a cylindrical probability on $S$ and it satisfies a very particular "tightness" condition : for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact subset $K$ of $S$ such that

$$\forall E\in\mathscr F,\qquad\Bigl((\pi_E)_\ast\mu\Bigr)\Bigl((S/E)\setminus\pi_E(K)\Bigr)\leq\varepsilon.$$

It can be shown that conversely, a cylindrical probability on $S$ that satisfies this tightness condition is the family of finite dimensional marginals of one and only one Radon probability on $S$. This can be seen as a consequence of a theorem of Prokhorov concerning the existence and uniqueness of projective limits of bounded Radon measures. So in particular, the finite dimensional marginals of a Radon probability $\mu$ completely determine $\mu$.

---

**Some references**

You can find out about Prokhorov's theorem in Laurent Schwartz' book *Radon measures on arbitrary topological spaces and cylindrical measures* ([Zbl 0298.28001](https://zbmath.org/0298.28001)), part I, chap. I, §10, thm. 22. It should also be present in [Prokhorov's original paper](https://www.mathnet.ru/eng/tvp4997) (but I couldn't pinpoint the exact whereabouts of the relevant theorem) and you can also get it from Bourbaki's [*Integration*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-07931-7), chap. IX, §4, n°2, thm. 1.

If you want to learn more about cylindrical probabilities, you can check out the part II of L. Schwartz' book and the chap. IX, §6 of Bourbaki's *Integration*. Aside from the "projective system" point of view on cylindrical probabilities, there is an "additive set function" point of view which you can get from Gel'fand & Vilenkin's book *Generalized functions. Vol. 4: Applications of harmonic analysis* ([Zbl 0136.11201](https://zbmath.org/0136.11201)), chap. IV.

Comment: very nice answer. It's nice to learn that there is indeed the concept of finite-dimensional marginal distributions on a Banach space. I try to find a reference where it is shown that a cylindrical probability that satisfies the tightness condition is the finite-dimensional of one particular measure on the space.

Comment: @SydAmerikaner This is the object of Prokhorov's theorem. Maybe it wasn't clear the way I phrased things. I'll do a quick edit.